# Image not rendering when uploading user image

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

On a user page, I select a file to upload a user photo. Once I select the image to use, the file is not rendered and the save button on the dialog pop up is disabled. However, this issue does not occur when in the Configuration -> Server administration -> File Uploads -> Documents and Media -> Allowed File Extensions is set to *.

However, setting * is not the desired solution as I need to restrict the file types.

Comment: Any error log on server console? or on javascript console?

Comment: Error is giving a FileExtensionException: null. So is it possible that when I upload a jpeg for example, liferay is not reading it as jpeg??

Comment: You can specify jpeg as allowed extension.

Comment: jepg is in the allowed extension. Actually here are my extensions allowed : .bmp,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.tif,.tiff,.svg. However, I am still getting the FileExtensionException null error